# 2d game with png sequences slowing on Unity3d

Tags: 2d, unity, spritesheet

We are building a tower defence game,In which enemy movement is done through sprite sheets as well the tower rotation is also done through sprites...every tower and every enemy has its own script attached to it which controle its animation...but when enemies and towers are in greater ammount the games slows down..and become laggy on iphone and unity ..can anyone tell what is the problem with it...

Comment: Do you have Unity Pro?  Have you tried using the profiler?

Comment: It is hard to see the performance problem without seeing the scripts. Maybe you could provide us with a pasebin link to your script?

Answer (score 1):

In a personal project of mine having a script working on every object in the game would slow the game down drastically. Thus creating a main object that controls multiple things should give a performance increase

Comment: Welcome to GDSE Roy! We typically like our answers to be a bit more in-depth. Perhaps if you could link to references or explain the reason for the slow down further that would make this answer better. Thanks for your contribution.